# selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

options = Options()
# Set any options you need for Chrome
# options.add_argument('--headless') # Example for headless mode

# Using ChromeDriverManager to handle the Chrome driver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

# Open the website
driver.get("https://online.singaporepools.com/en/sports")

# Wait for the page to load
time.sleep(6)

WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "upcomingFootball_filterBetType")))
# Locate the dropdown menu
dropdown = Select(driver.find_element(By.NAME, "upcomingFootball_filterBetType"))
# dropdown.click()

# Select the "1/2 Goal" option
dropdown.select_by_value("WH")

# Rest of your code
```

For the following above I got exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\C_Drive\Dropbox\Important\Python_Code\self_util\football\4_football_login.py", line 34, in <module>
    dropdown.select_by_value("WH")
  File "D:\C_Drive\Hardlink\Users\TTHCMM\Envs\generic\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", line 79, in select_by_value
    self._set_selected(opt)
  File "D:\C_Drive\Hardlink\Users\TTHCMM\Envs\generic\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", line 214, in _set_selected
    option.click()
  File "D:\C_Drive\Hardlink\Users\TTHCMM\Envs\generic\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 94, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "D:\C_Drive\Hardlink\Users\TTHCMM\Envs\generic\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 395, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "D:\C_Drive\Hardlink\Users\TTHCMM\Envs\generic\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 348, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\C_Drive\Hardlink\Users\TTHCMM\Envs\generic\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
  (Session info: chrome=120.0.6099.130)
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00796EE3+174339]
    (No symbol) [0x006C0A51]
    (No symbol) [0x003D6FF6]
    (No symbol) [0x003DAEAC]
    (No symbol) [0x003DC585]
    (No symbol) [0x003DC622]
    (No symbol) [0x0040C529]
    (No symbol) [0x00402D63]
    (No symbol) [0x0042700C]
    (No symbol) [0x004025B0]
    (No symbol) [0x00427414]
    (No symbol) [0x0043A104]
    (No symbol) [0x00426DA6]
    (No symbol) [0x00401034]
    (No symbol) [0x00401F8D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00834B1C+820540]
    sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x008F53EE+653550]
    sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x008F4E09+652041]
    sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x008E97CC+605388]
    sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x008F5D9B+656027]
    (No symbol) [0x006CFE6C]
    (No symbol) [0x006C83B8]
    (No symbol) [0x006C84DD]
    (No symbol) [0x006B5818]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7674FCC9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77E17C6E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77E17C3E+238]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

How to handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting `ElementNotInteractableException` because during load your resource generates several invisible containers with dropdown with name `upcomingFootball_filterBetType`.

So when you're getting first element, it is actually a backdrop that doesn't have size or location and exception is thrown.

However, indicator of rendered tab is container that has selector `.tab-pane.active` .
You should just wait for it's visibility and get inner dropdown element.

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
dropdown_container = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".tab-pane.active [name=upcomingFootball_filterBetType]")))
dropdown = Select(dropdown_container)
dropdown.select_by_value("WH")
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, do you know what is the reason where multiple invisible containers available?

Comment: @william007 it is site rendering logic. When you load it, you can see for some time that button 'Display' is disabled and has text `Loading`. During that time dropdown is actually a backdrop. Site shows you some content but it is still not ready to process it. That is usually made to not to let users to close the page by showing partially rendered site. Statistically users don't like to wait too long for load and close site if it doesn't show output for 5+ seconds. Backdrops solve this.